# No internet connection after ubuntu server 20.04 install

Tags: networking, ubuntu-forums

[image]
Did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04. When I try to install any package, it gives me the below error:

"Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80"

Can someone please help to resolve the issue

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1302433/edit) to show us 1) The your complete netplan settings (in /etc/netplan/*), 2) The complete output of `ip addr`, and 3) The complete output of `route`.

Comment: @user535733 Added the screen shot

Comment: Next time, please use copy/paste for text output instead of screenshots. Your Ubuntu server did acquire a LAN IP address: 10.166.120.8, just like you told it to, so looks like your Ubuntu server is working properly. Check the settings on your Gateway or Router, to ensure that you are really permitting network access by that server. Of course, that's a Networking issue, not an Ubuntu-related issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While running "apt-get update"
or something just add "-o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true"
something like:

> apt-get update -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true

but to solve this problem permanently create a file with "99force-ipv4 in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/" directory and add following stuff:

> Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";

Comment: Thanks , I also had to add Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxyaddress:proxyport"; in the /etc/apt/apt.conf file

Comment: just mark this question as solved if it helped you.